# How to show Facebook like feed for multiple images Grid in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-recyclerview

I am using Recyler view with gridlayoutmanager am able to show with vertical orientation for Gridlayoutmanager if i use horizontal orientation i am getting scroll for grid

Comment: Hello please see this example : https://abhilunagaria.blogspot.in/2016/06/best-way-to-display-multiple-image-grid_8.html